# Python: Looping over One Dictionary and Creating Key/Value Pairs in a New Dictionary if Conditions Are Met

Tags: python, dictionary, conditional-statements, key, iteration

I want to compare the values of one dictionary to the values of a second dictionary.  If the values meet certain criteria, I want to create a third dictionary with keys and value pairs that will vary depending on the matches.

Here is a contrived example that shows my problem.

*edit: sorry about all the returns, but stack overflow is not recognizing single returns and is running 3-4 lines onto one line, making the code illegible.  also, it's not greying out my code as code.  don't know why.*

```
employee = {'skills': 'superintendent', 'teaches': 'social studies', 
            'grades': 'K-12'}
school_districts = {0: {'needs':  'superintendent', 'grades': 'K-12'}, 
                    1:{'needs': 'social_studies', 'grades': 'K-12'}}
jobs_in_school_district = {}
for key in school_districts:
    if (employee['skills'] == school_districts[key]['needs']):
        jobs_in_school_district[key] = {}
        jobs_in_school_district[key]['best_paying_job'] = 'superintendent'

    if (employee['teaches'] == school_districts[key]['needs']):
        jobs_in_school_district[key] = {}
        jobs_in_school_district[key]['other_job'] = 'social_studies_teacher'

print(jobs_in_school_district)
```

This is the value I want to see for 'jobs_in_school_district ':

```
{0: {'best_paying_job': 'superintendent'}, 
 1: {'other_job': 'social_studies_teacher'}}
```

This is what I'm getting:

```
{1: {'other_job': 'social_studies_teacher'}}
```

I understand what's wrong here. Python is setting `jobs_in_school_district` equal to `{0: {'best_paying_job': 'superintendent'}` after the first if block (lines 6-8).  Then it executes the second if block (line 10).  But then it overwrites the `{0: {'best_paying_job': 'superintendent'}` at line 11 and creates an empty dict again.  Then it assigns 1: {'other_job': 'social_studies_teacher'}' to `jobs_in_school_district` at line 12.

But if I eliminate the two `jobs_in_school_district[key] = {}` in each of the for blocks (lines 7 and 11) and just put one before the 'for' statement (new line 5) like this:

```
jobs_in_school_district[key] = {}

for key in school_districts:
    if (employee['skills'] == school_districts[key]['needs']):
        jobs_in_school_district[key]['best_paying_job'] = 'superintendent'

    if (employee['teaches'] == jobs[key]['needs']):
        jobs_in_school_district[key]['other_job'] = 'social_studies_teacher'

print(jobs_in_school_district)
```

It will only check the first key in the 'school_districts' dict and then stop (it stops looping I guess, I don't know), so I get this:

```
jobs_in_school_district = {0: {'best_paying_job': 'superintendent'}
```

(I've tried re-writing it a few times and sometimes I get a "key error" instead).

First question: why doesn't that second block of code work?
Second question: how do I write code so it does work?

(I don't really understand 'next' (method or function) and what it does, so if I have to use it, could you please explain? Thanks).

Comment: You should read up on how to format code samples here, this is unreadable.

Comment: Unless there's some way to force it, it's refusing to do it.

Answer (score 3):

Simplest fix (and answer to your first question): `key` is not properly defined in your latest snippets, the assignment must be *inside* the `for` though outside the `if`s:

```
for key in school_districts:
    jobs_in_school_district[key] = {}
    if ... etc etc ...

    if ... other etc etc ...
```

Simplest may actually be to use "default dicts" instead of plain ones:

```
import collections
jobs_in_school_district = collections.defaultdict(dict)
```

Now you can remove the assignment to the `[key]` indexing and it will be done for you, automatically, if and when needed for the first time for any given key.

Answer (score 0):

Try placing

```
jobs_in_school_district[key] = {}
```

after the for loop but before the if statements.

And yea the formatting is unreadable.

Answer (score 0):

If you change social_studies to social studies without the underscore the code works as you expected.  See this line:

```
school_districts = {0: {'needs':  'superintendent', 'grades': 'K-12'}, 
                    1:{'needs': 'social_studies', 'grades': 'K-12'}}
```