# Change value which is a key in the same dictionary: Python

Tags: python, dictionary, key

Input :

```
oldNames = { 'Fruits':['orange', 'Banana', 'Peach', 'mango', 'raspberries']
          'Meat': ['Bacon', 'Chicken', 'Ham', 'Steak']
          'Food': ['Fruits', 'Rice', 'Beans', 'Meat'] }
```

Sample Code:

```
oldNames = {}   # Defining the dictionary I am creating from the file
newNames = {}   # Defining another dictionary where I am planning to change the values 
Keys_ = []   # Defining the list to append new values for new dictionary 
Values_ = []

def dict_parse():
    infiles = [f for f in os.listdir(path) if f.endswith('.pin')]    # First few lines gets the match fromt he input file
    for infile in infiles:
        with open(path + '/' + infile, 'r') as inFile:

            infileContents = inFile.read()
            PATTERN = re.compile(r'Group (\w+)\s+([^\n]+)\s*\{(.*?)\}', re.DOTALL);


            for match in PATTERN.finditer(infileContents):
                keyname = match.group(1).strip()
                elements = match.group(3).replace(',', '').split()
                oldNames[keyname] = elements  # I get the correct dictionary values until here. 

                for keyname, elements in oldNames.items():     # iterating over the keys and values of existing dict
                    for element in elements: # iterating over values
                        if (element in oldNames[keyname]):     # condition to check if vlaue is a key
                            newNames = {}
                            for i in range(len(oldNames[keyname])):
                                Values_.append( oldNames[keyname][i])     # This part is wrong but not sure how to modify
                                newNames= dict((k,v) for k,v in (oldNames[keyname], Values_))     # This is not the correct format to form the dict I guess... 
                        else:
                            newNames = dict((k,v) for k,v in oldNames[keyname])


                print new_pinNames["Food"]



if __name__ =='__main__':
    dict_parse()
```

I have the values as a list. I am using a `for loop` to iterate through the list of values and another `for loop` to iterate over the values of the keys matched. I need the output as a single list with the values of the keys replaced and is in the same position as it was before. Posted a sample output for reference.

I am printing out one key but what I need is a new dictionary with all the values found and replaced.

Expected Output:

```
['orange', 'Banana', 'Peach', 'mango', 'raspberries',  'Rice', 'Beans', 'Bacon', 'Chicken', 'Ham', 'Steak']
```

Reference:

```
Used this : [This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3162166/python-looping-over-one-dictionary-and-creating-key-value-pairs-in-a-new-dictio)
```

---

Comment: You're forgetting commas in your dictionary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will work... however, it can definitely get confusing when using comprehension syntax to achieve such complexity.

```
print dict(
    [(key, [y for x in [[i] if i not in oldNames else oldNames[i]
        for i in value] for y in x])
    for key, value in oldNames.items()])
```

So, what you *can* do instead (if it's too convoluted for you) is write it out like this:

```
newNames = {}
for key, value in oldNames.items():
    valueLists = [[i] if i not in oldNames else oldNames[i] for i in value]
    newNames[key] = []
    for valueList in valueLists:
         newNames[key].extend(valueList)

print newNames
```

**Explanation**:
Essentially, the resulting `valueLists` in the first loop would look like this:

```
# Using the 'Food' key
[['orange', 'Banana', 'Peach', 'mango', 'raspberries'], ['Rice'], ['Beans'], ['Bacon', 'Chicken', 'Ham', 'Steak']]
```

A list of lists (even for single elements) is created intentionally so that it can later be flattened uniformally (*across all items*), without caring if some of the items actually didn't have any nested key values (like `fruits`). This makes it easy to add or remove items that do have key-value nesting and expect the same behaviour to work *all the time*.

```
    # Here I iterate through valueLists, thus the first
    # item in the loop would be (using the above example):
    # ['orange', 'Banana', 'Peach', 'mango', 'raspberries'] 
    for valueList in valueLists:
        # Finally, the `extend` flattens it completely.
        newNames[key].extend(valueList)
```

The **output**:

```
{'Food': ['orange', 'Banana', 'Peach', 'mango', 'raspberries', 'Rice', 'Beans', 'Bacon', 'Chicken', 'Ham', 'Steak'], 'Meat': ['Bacon', 'Chicken', 'Ham', 'Steak'], 'Fruits': ['orange', 'Banana', 'Peach', 'mango', 'raspberries']}
```

Comment: Thanks! It works now. I was not doing the list of lists like you have done and was not able to generate the final result and thanks for the explanation.